# .NET 2.0 code - Unit testing with MoQ

Tags: .net, testing

I am building a .NET 2.0 codebase, and i want to use any test framework library for unit testing the .NET 2.0 codebase. There are some build using .NET 3.5, is it still OK i use it as my unit testing tool to test .NET 2.0 code?

Answer (score 4):

Definitely OK to use Moq to test a 2.0 code base. For a long time we had only .NET 2.0 assemblies and applications but still created .NET 3.5 SP1 class library projects for testing with NUnit and Moq.